# sslVerifyClientStatus=optional equivalent in envoy-proxy?

Tags: envoyproxy

Just like in nginx, we can implement by using this below example :

```
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/root-ca/acme-ca-bundle.pem;
        ssl_verify_client optional;

 location / {
            if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
                return 400 "No required SSL Certificate was sent";
                break;
            }
        }
```

In the above example, how do we implement in envoy-proxy, yes googled and found this  mtls in envoy - https://github.com/salrashid123/envoy_mtls
yet trying to understand if theres condition to ignore mTLS for "/healthcheck" and enforce mTLS for "/" ?